# app engine rails request.remote_ip values seems incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to validate cron.yaml requests based on request.remote_ip.

Doc says that it would return 10.0.0.1 but the value returned is '2002:a51:bf0a::'

Issue with gcloud or do i need to check some other request field?

Comment: One's an IPv4 address, the other is an IPv6 one. Docs may need an update if they switched to IPv6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other addresses are load balancer ones. Hence need to check 'X-Forwarded-For'header values.